# Replacing a \t with something in a list

Tags: python, regex

```
>>>user_sentence = "hello \t how are you?"
>>>import re
>>>user_sentenceSplit = re.findall(r"([\s]|[\w']+|[.,!?;])",user_sentence)
>>>print user_sentenceSplit
```

I get `['hello', '\t', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?']`

I don't know how to create any code that will replace the `'\t'` with `'tab'`.

Comment: `str.replace` does not work?

Comment: That replacing before tokenizing won't work if the tab is enclosed with word chars. It must be done inside a list comprehension or a loop. Something like `user_sentenceSplit = [x.replace("\t", "tab") for x in re.findall(r"(\s|[\w']+|[.,!?;])",user_sentence)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that replacing `\t` in the original string will ever work, you have two issues:

- Your code also outputs spaces as tokens, but you do not want to have them
- The `\t` in between letters will become a part of a word token.

So, you need to replace `[\s]` with `[^\S ]` pattern that matches any whitespace but a regular space (add more excluded whitespace symbols if necessary into the negated character class) and you need to iterate through all the tokens and check if a token is equal to a tab, and then replace it with `tab` value. So, the best is to use `re.finditer` and push the found values into a list variable, see sample code below:

```
import re
user_sentence = "hello \t how are you?"
user_sentenceSplit = []
for x in re.finditer(r"[^\S ]|[\w']+|[.,!?;]",user_sentence):
    if x.group() == "\t": # if it is a tab, replace the value
        user_sentenceSplit.append("tab")
    else:  # else, push the match value
        user_sentenceSplit.append(x.group()) 
print(user_sentenceSplit)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sbn0Dp)

Answer (score 1):

I think `str.replace` would do the job.

```py
user_sentence.replace('\t', 'tab')
```

Do this before splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

It is behavior of Python's compiler. You should not be worrying about it. Pyhton's Compiler store `tab` as `\t`. You need not to do anything on it as it will treat it as tab while performing any action over it. For example:

```
>>> my_string = 'Yes    Hello   So?'  # <- String with tab
>>> my_string  
'Yes\tHello\tSo?'    # <- Stored tab as '\t'
>>> print my_string
Yes Hello   So?   # While printing, again tab
```

However you exact requirement is not clear to me. In case you want to replace the value of `\t` with `tab` string, you may do:

```
>>> my_string = my_string.replace('\t', 'tab')
>>> my_string
'YestabHellotabSo?'
```

where `my_string` is holding the value I mentioned in previous example.